# HTML 5 - addEventListener explanation

Tags: alert, addeventlistener, status, offline-caching, application-cache

What does the following code mean? Especially the "if" section. Why does the `alert` only fire sometimes?

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
  if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY)
    window.location.reload();

  alert('done');
}, false);
```

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```
function foo(e) 
  {
  /* If the status is UPDATEREADY, reload the page */
  if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY)
    {
    window.location.reload();
    }

  /* Alert 'done' (reload has precedence) */ 
  alert('done');
  }

/* Add a new event which bubbles up and calls foo, but does not capture */
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', foo, false);
```

**References**

- [Cordova Issue #5664: AppCache's "checking" event fired more than once per App startup](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5664)
- [Application cache API: UPDATEREADY (numeric value 4)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/obsolete.html#dom-applicationcache-updateready)